# Spark map vs foreachRdd

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming application where we receive a dstream from kafka and need to store to dynamoDB ....i'm experimenting with two ways to do it as described in the code below

**requestsWithState is a Dstream**

**Code Snippet 1 with foreachRDD:**

```
requestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   println("Data being populated to Pulsar")
   rdd.foreach { case (id, eventStream) =>
     println("id is " + id + " Event is " + eventStream)
     DBUtils.putItem(dynamoConnection, id, eventStream.toString())
   }
}
```

**Code Snippet 2 with map:**

```
   requestsWithState.map (rdd => { rdd match {
         case (id, eventStream) => {
           println("id is " + id + " Event is " + eventStream)
           val dynamoConnection = setupDynamoClientConnection()
           DBUtils.putItem(dynamoConnection, id, eventStream.toString())
         }
       }
     })

 requestsWithState.print(1)
```

**Code Snippet1 work's fine and populates the database...the second code snippet doesn't work ....we are newbie's to spark and would love to know the reason behind it and the way to get it working ?** ........the reason we are experimenting ( we know it's a transformation and foreachRdd is an action) is foreachRdd is very slow for our use case with heavy load on a cluster and we found that map is much faster if we can get it working.....please help us get map code working

Comment: You should (almost) NEVER have side effects in map or flatMap!

Answer (score 1):

Map is a type of  transformation(lazy transformation) in Spark and will not execute unless you call an spark action after this . 
For Spark transformation and actions , refers to the below link 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations

Comment: .....i do have an action after map requestsWithState.print(1) but still it doesn't work i have updated the question accordingly please take a look

Comment: RDDs are immutable , so map would return a new rdd . So try with `code` requestsWithState =  requestsWithState.map (rdd => { rdd match {
         case (id, eventStream) => {
           println("id is " + id + " Event is " + eventStream)
           val dynamoConnection = setupDynamoClientConnection()
           DBUtils.putItem(dynamoConnection, id, eventStream.toString())
         }
       }
     })

 requestsWithState.print(1) `code`

Answer (score 1):

DStream.map returns another stream. You should invoke print on that stream rather than the original one.

So in Scala:

```
val transformedStream = requestsWithState.map (rdd => { rdd match {
         case (id, eventStream) => {
           println("id is " + id + " Event is " + eventStream)
           val dynamoConnection = setupDynamoClientConnection()
           DBUtils.putItem(dynamoConnection, id, eventStream.toString())
         }
       }
     })

transformedStream.print(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The version with `map` doesn't have any actions and `.map` is not an action, but transformation.

Transformations are not executed without action.

See e.g. http://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf or http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations

Comment: i do have an action after map requestsWithState.print(1) but still it doesn't work i have updated the question accordingly please take a look

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution for your problem since you add an action requestsWithState.print(1) ??
I know this is an old question but i am interresting by your use case. Thanks